# Why does a real/virtual photon interact only with charged particle?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, wave-particle-duality

A photon is the force carrier of an electromagnetic wave and it consists of an electric and a magnetic field propagating through space at the speed of light in vacuum.

It exhibits *wave-particle duality* and does not interact with another photon. The fact that it interacts only with charged particles also implies that it does not interact with magnetic fields.

A photon has an entourage of electrons and perhaps other stuff around it and, especially, in a particle accelerator energetic photons may collide in this way.

**Questions**:

**Q1**. How is this possible?

**Q2**. Why do photons only interact with charged particles?

P.S: A picture is worth a thousand words: I don't have quantum physics background. I read Maxwell's equations and they only apply to waves. I peeked at Einstein's photoelectric effect paper but it only describes how light behaves like a particle.

Comment: [Photons can interact with other photons...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-photon_physics)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1: For photons of energies much less gamma rays, the quantum mechanical photon-photon interaction is negligible. This is consistent with the classical electrodynamic description where the principle of superposition holds (electromagnetic waves pass through each other unchanged, as well as through electric/magnetic fields).

Q2: in reality, charge is defined as how strongly a particle interacts with photons, so this question is not valid.